# how to check whether the current time is between a preset time frame in android

Tags: java, android, date, time

Hai i have a problem right now, i want to check whether the current time say(10;00am) is between a preset time
frame say (10:00 pm - 4:00 am) how can i do that.
I have tried something not always the condition is satisfied

```
public class Test {

    static int flag;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // final Timer timer = new Timer();
        // Timer timer2 = new Timer();

        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm");
        Date start = null;
        Date end = null;
        try {
            start = parser.parse("22.00");
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            end = parser.parse("8.00");
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Date userDate = parser.parse("23.06");
            if (userDate.after(start) && userDate.before(end)) {
                System.out.println("innnnnnnnnnnn");
            } else {
                System.out.println("outttttttttt");
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // Invalid date was entered
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Avoid j.u.Date

Generally, the java.util.Date and .Calendar and SimpleDateFormat classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome and should be avoided. Specifically for your needs, they combine date *and* time-of-day whereas you seem to want only time-of-day.

Use a decent date-time library instead.

- For Java, that means either:

  - [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
  - [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), new in [Java 8.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29)
- For Android, that means [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

## LocalTime

Joda-Time (and java.time) provide a LocalTime class to represent time-of-day without any time zone. When getting the current time, you should pass a DateTimeZone to adjust your computer's/JVM's date-time to the desired time zone rather than the default.

## Half-Open

Usually in date-time work, the best way to compare a span of time is using the "half-open" approach. With half-open the beginning is *inclusive* and the ending is *exclusive*. Notice the comparisons in this example code using Joda-Time 2.3.

## Joda-Time Example

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now( timeZone ); // Adjust computer/JVM time zone's current time to desired time zone's current time.
LocalTime start = new LocalTime( "10:00:00" );
LocalTime stop = new LocalTime( "16:00:00" );
boolean isNotBeforeStart = ( ! now.isBefore( start ) );  // Is now equal to or after start?
boolean isBeforeEnd = now.isBefore( stop ); // Is now any time up to, but not including, stop?
boolean isWithinRange = ( isNotBeforeStart && isBeforeEnd );
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand your approach, but you might be forgetting that a java.util.Date instance represents a particular moment in time. In other words, it always describes a particular time on a particular day. However, you want it to describe the time 23:06 on *any* day.

You can get the individual fields (day, month, year, hour, etc.) by using a Calendar instead of a Date:

```
    Date yourDateObject = ...;
    GregorianCalendar timeToCheck = new GregorianCalendar();
    timeToCheck.setTime(yourDateObject);
    int hour = timeToCheck.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    if (hour >= 22 || hour < 8) {
        System.out.println("It's between 10 PM and 8 AM");
    }
```